# Написание библиотеки Objective-C

Tags: data-structures, xcode, objective-c

Привет всем. Я новичек в Objective-C и я задался таким вопросом, как собственно написать свою библиотеку и как ее впоследствии подключать к своим новым проектам. Библиотека будет включать работу со структурами данных типа стек, очередь, дерево.
Надеюсь тут подскажут, гугление ничего толком не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

приведу пример библиотеки, я ее недавно подключал к приложению, поэтому она мне первой пришла в голову.

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/master/src/fmdb

библиотека работает с базой sqlite, это папка с файлами h & m, скачиваешь как zip архив, подключаешь как фреймворк в xcode(просто надо добавить папку целиком в группу проекта frameworks) и используешь в своей проекте.

Comment: т.е. я просто создаю грубо говоря проект библиотеки
тестирую его, а в дальнейшем просто копирую эту папку(содержащую *.h & *.m файлы) к своему новому проекту путем File-> Add file to "name my project" ? Я правильно понял?

Comment: да, очень удобно